# How to serve both dynamic and static pages with Dart and shelf?

Tags: dart, dart-shelf

Using `shelf_static` to serve static web pages through Dart is no problem:

```dart
var staticHandler = createStaticHandler(staticPath, defaultDocument:'home.html');
io.serve(staticHandler, 'localhost', port).then((server) {
  print('Serving at http://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
});
```

and I can use `shelf_route` fine for dynamic web pages:

```dart
Router routes = new Router()
  ..get('/item/{itemid}', handler.doItem);
var handler = const shelf.Pipeline()
  .addHandler(routes.handler);

io.serve(handler, 'localhost', port).then((server) {
  print('Serving at http://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
});
```

But I'm struggling with adding a static handler to the dynamic version.
Things I've tried include:

```dart
Router routes = new Router()
  ..get('/item/{itemid}', handler.doItem)
  ..get('/', staticHandler);
```

or ...

```dart
  ..get('/.*', staticHandler);
```

or ...

```dart
  ..get('/{any}', staticHandler);
```

All of which give me the specified default `home.html` page if I request `http://localhost:8080/` but explicitly asking for an existing page `http://localhost:8080/home.html` gives me Not Found.

Should I not even be trying to do this with `shelf_static`? If not, what would be the correct approach?
Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`Cascade`](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/shelf/0.5.6/index.html#shelf/shelf.Cascade). It creates a chain of handlers, moving to the next one if the previous one gives a 404 or 405 response.

```dart
var staticHandler = createStaticHandler(staticPath, defaultDocument:'home.html');
var routes = new Router()
    ..get('/item/{itemid}', handleItem);

var handler = new Cascade()
    .add(staticHandler)
    .add(routes.hander)
    .handler;
io.serve(handler, 'localhost', port).then((server) {
  print('Serving at http://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
});
```

Comment: Ah - that's better than just the fallback handler. Excellent.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is that the `shelf_route` methods like `get` must fully match the path. With static files you don't want exact matches as the remainder of the path tells you the path to the file.

For this you need to use the `add` method and set `exactMatch: false` as currently the methods like `get`, `post` etc don't expose `exactMatch`.

The following works

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {

  Logger.root.onRecord.listen(print);

  var staticHandler = createStaticHandler('../static', defaultDocument:'home.html');

  final root = router()
    ..get('/item/{itemid}', (Request request) => 'handling the item')
    ..add('/', ['GET'], staticHandler, exactMatch: false);

  printRoutes(root);

  io.serve(root.handler, InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V6, 9999);

}
```

FYI I've added a higher level framework called [mojito](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mojito) that is a thin glue layer on many of the shelf components that makes this a little easier.

It's still kinda newish and poorly documented but in case you're interested you can do the following

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {

  Logger.root.onRecord.listen(print);

  final app = mojito.init();

  app.router
    ..get('/item/{itemid}', (String itemid) => 'handling the item $itemid')
    ..addStaticAssetHandler('/', fileSystemPath: '../static', 
        defaultDocument:'home.html');

  app.start();
}
```

`addStaticAssetHandler` calls `createStaticHandler` behind the scenes but also supports invoking pub serve in development mode which is very handy for stuff like polymer

Answer (score 3):

A `fallbackHandler` can be specified for the `Router`. It appears that using the static handler here solves the problem.

```dart
Router routes = new Router(fallbackHandler: staticHandler)
  ..get('/item/{itemid}', handler.doItem);
```